# QT Framework update from 4.7.2 to 5.2.1, QT doesn't want to configure and gives fatal error

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, nmake

QT Framework update from 4.7.2 to 5.2.1
So I am trying to get my musicbot plugin up to date again. 
I am now having difficulty getting qt framework 5.2.1 installed.
So after 1 week of struggling I decided to take a rest and make a post about this.

To be more clear on my situation and what my problem is I try to explain what i did.

So I download the file qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1.zip and extracted it to the directory `C:\QT\32bits\5.2.1 and C:\QT\64bits\5.2.1`.

than I open up MSVC2010 prompt for x86 or amd64.
Than I go the the directories described above and try to configure the qt framework.
In this process I get a strange error that I can find on Google but the explanation consist only of disabled anti-virus or check your file permissions.

After executing the following command:

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2010 -release -nomake examples -opensource -no-opengl
```

I get this output (including the error):

```
Creating qmake...

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Running configuration tests...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x463'
Stop.
Could not find output file: No such file or directory
```

Well it still creates a qmake.exe file so I tried this file anyways but than I got this error.

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '..\..\..\QT\32bits\5.2.1\mksp
ecs\default\qmake.conf'
```

Comment: Have you tried to install fresh add-in for VS? Try it: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.3-opensource.exe

Comment: Are you sure that you set env. var. QTDIR correctly? And env. var. PATH? Are you sure that you configured add-in of VS?

Comment: depends ofcourse by what you mean correct :-)
I edited the Path and added the QTDIR to the env var. so that should be okeej.

Comment: If you like, you can take a look through teamviewer

Comment: well i build inside a virtual-box. so i can do a clean win7 installation and try to do this from scratch. because i had 4.7.2 installed before. just hard to figure out where to start? just install MSVC2010 Ultimate and than qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2010-5.2.1.exe and then the one you send. http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.3-opensource.exe

Comment: Ok, this is great, that you can do clean experiment!

Comment: In that case I will try this first in the 3 steps i described . this will take some time so I will come back with results when I have them.

Comment: Try to reconfigure it without "-nomake examples" option

Comment: Well after reinstalling the Windows7 inside VirtualBox and than installing Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate + qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2010-5.2.1.exe + http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.3-opensource.exe this did the trick for me.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL FOR ALL THE HELP YOU HAVE GIVEN ME! It feels good knowing I didn't needed to do this on my own but had help. Thnxs

Answer (score 0):

Try with the latest release.
1. Download QtBase source code:
http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.2/submodules/qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.2.7z
2. Extract.
3. Do a shadow build:

```
mkdir build
cd build
..\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.2\configure -nomake examples -nomake tests -opensource -confirm-license -opengl desktop -shared -release -platform win32-msvc2010
nmake
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention this. but I am writing a plugin for teamspeak3. and Teamspeak 3 is based on the qt frameworks 5.2.1 so I need to work with the same version.

Comment: You can download prebuild binaries for MSVC2010 and MinGW from http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.1/